# find/select first 250 characters in a html text

Tags: c#, html, regex

For example:

```
<p class="Pa0" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;"><span class="A1"><span style="font-size: 10pt;">Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers</span></span></p>Giving this flyer to your class customers Giving this flyer to your class customers
```

Regex:

```
<[^<>]+>[^<>.!?]{250}
```

It should select all the first 250 characters ignoring html tags. It ignores first html tag occurance but selects the second

Comment: what about htmlagilitypack?

Comment: Use an HTML Parser. Too many variable conditions at play here HTML Agility Pack for example

Comment: Stack Overflow does not write code for you on demand. Please share what you have tried.

Comment: The user is not asking a question; This is called demanding! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using find since the control was in user control page. Else class name is sufficient

```
$("#id").find(".class").each(function (i) {
    var len = $(this).text().length;
    if (len > 250) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 250) + '...');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is something more elegant out there, but as you didn't try that hard to format your question, I'm gonna try something different, just for the sake of it. It works, nonetheless.

```
var str = @"<p>something here<H3>Title</H3></p>";

// Add and remove "<" chars on the stack. When we don't have any "<"
// chars on the stack, it means we're in the contents sections of the tag.
var stack = new Stack<string>();
// Avoid peeking an empty stack.
stack.Push("base");

// This will be your resulting string and number of chars.
var result = "";
var resultLimit = 5;

foreach (var ch in str)
{
    // Limit reached.
    if (result.Count() == resultLimit)
        break;

    // Entering a tag.
    if (ch == '<')
        { stack.Push("start"); continue; }

    // Leaving a tag.
    if (ch == '>')
        { stack.Pop(); continue; }

    // We're not in a tag at the moment, so take this char.
    if (stack.Peek() != "start")
        result += ch;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex is working as expected, you didn't anchor it to the start of your string, so when it couldn't match on the first `<p>` tag it proceeds forward through your string looking for a match.  It also couldn't match on the second tag, the `<span class="A1">` so it continues on until it finds a place where it can match.

That place turns out to be the third HTML tag, the `<span style="font-size: 10pt;">` tag which is the first tag to be followed by 250 non `<>.!?` characters, so it matches that tag and the following 250 chars.

So, all working as expected.

Comment: Thank you @Smathy for taking a look. Using regex i was not able to achieve what I needed. Was able to find the solution today using simple jquery.